# How to extract only the 1st 2 bytes of data from CFReadStream in Objective-C for iPhone programming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cfreadstream

1. How can I read the data from read stream in Objective-C? The code below would give me how many bytes are read from stream, but how can I know what data is read from stream?

   ```
   CFIndex cf = CFReadStreameRead(Stream, buffer, length);
   ```
2. How can I extract only the 1st 2bytes of data in the read stream in Objective-C? For example, if this is the data from stream:

   ```
   017MacApp
   ```

   1st byte has 0 in it, and 2nd byte has 17 in it.

   How do I extract 0 and 17 into byte array?

I know that the below code would give me back the byte array to int value.

```
((b[0] & 0xFF) << 8)+ (b[1] & 0xFF);
```

but how to put 0 into b[0] and 17 into b[1]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
uint8_t buffer[2];
CFIndex cf = CFReadStreamRead(Stream, buffer, 2);
if (cf == 2)
{
    uint8_t firstByte = buffer[0];
    uint8_t secondByte = buffer[1];
}
else
{
    // cf == -1 => error, cf == 0 => end of file, cf == 1 => you need to call again to get the second byte
}
```

Here is the [Apple doc](http://gemma.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFReadStreamRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFReadStreamRead).